# Deployment of Multiple SSIS Packages to MSDB using an automated script

Tags: deployment, ssis

i want to deploy set of packages from different folders to MSDB using an automated script say power-shell
. i have a script which can deploy to integration services catalogue. But unable to do the same for MSDB?

Comment: Package based deployment is a very outdated way of using SSIS, are you not able to use SSIS Projects and just deploy the entire project?

Comment: Yes i can but i want to push like 300 packages from different folders via a single script thats the issue. If you can suggest something

Comment: I would suggest putting them all into sensibly organised projects and deploying those instead...